# How to remove a translation using CakePHP 3 TranslateBehavior

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translate

I am using TranslateBehavior and it mostly works great. However there is a problem of removing translations.
I had this problem where empty strings were returned if they were present in i18n table, which makes sense. I set

```
allowEmptyTranslations => false
```

flag and it solved the problem but created another. I am now unable to remove translations. I tried leaving the fields empty or saving a single space. The first technique did not change the fields at all, the other did save, but I couldn't then change the space into anything else. If I try to input a new value, I get a duplicate row error directly from the database, so I assume the actual field was unset beforehand if there was only a space (Translate must have treated it as empty). Therefore it seems that allowEmptyTranslations works for both saving and retrieving.

In short des anybody know a way to remove translations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure what your duplicate row error problem is about, but if you want to actually save empty strings (or `null`s), then you'll have to enable `allowEmptyTranslations`, you could do that on the fly if you want.

Here's a quick and dirty example, where `$table` would be the table object that has the translate behavior attached, and `$entity` would be the entity for which you'd want to save translations:

```
// ...

$translateBehavior = $table->behaviors()->get('Translate');
$allowEmptyTranslations = $translateBehavior->getConfig('allowEmptyTranslations');
$translateBehavior->setConfig('allowEmptyTranslations', true);

$result = $table->save($entity);
// ...

$translateBehavior->setConfig('allowEmptyTranslations', $allowEmptyTranslations);
```

Alternatively you could also delete translation entries, here `$entity` would be the entity for which you'd want to remove a translation, let's say it belongs to a table class named `ArticlesTable`, and you'd want to remove the french translation for the `title` field:

```
$translateBehavior = $table->behaviors()->get('Translate');
$translationTable = $translateBehavior->getTableLocator()->get(
    $translateBehavior->getConfig('translationTable')
);

$translationEntity = $translationTable
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'foreign_key' => $entity->id,
        'model' => 'Articles',
        'field' => 'title',
        'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    ])
    ->firstOrFail();

$result = $translationTable->delete($translationEntity);
```

The examples are untested, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yeah, the first solution won't work since like I said enabling empty translations causes issues. I will try to build on your second idea and maybe try to stuff it into beforemarshal or something.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek You wrote that disabling causes issues with saving, not enabling!?

Comment: Yes and no. Disabling helps with saving, but breaks editing. Enabling helps with editing (kind of), but breaks saving in a way that every empty field in form gets saved